# LongPress Button with Status Indicator

Tags: flutter

I'm still rather new to Flutter and want to implement the following feature (and don't even yet have an idea how to approach):
On my screen I have multiple buttons (let's say 3). But those buttons should not fire directly when being tapped, but only after a certain duration (let's say 1 sec) - so some kind of LongPress. In addition to that I want to indicate to the user that something is happening and for this purpose I plan to show some kind of indicator (e.g. a simple container that fills up). This indicator only exists once on the screen and is shared by all buttons.

So to summarize, the "DelayedButton" should...

- OnTap: show a message ("Hold the button down to trigger the action")
- On Long Press Start: Start the animation that progresses the status indicator
- On Long Press End before the defined duration is elapsed: Reset the status indicator to 0 and show the same message as for OnTap
- When defined duration is elapsed while the user still holds down the button: trigger an action (which is obviously different for the different buttons...)

Can you provide some clues on how to approach this? Or is there even a package available for this?

Not sure if this might be relevant, but for state management I plan to use the provider library.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: There is an widget called `LongPressGestureRecognizer`. you can see how to use in  `flutter\lib\src\widgets\gesture_detector.dart` file. (Ctrl + Click on `GestureDetector` in Android studio)

Comment: you can specify duration of long press

Answer (score 1):

OK, after quiet some trial & error I came up with the following solution.
Since I am new to Flutter, I have no idea if it is good, clean, robust code or not (one "issue" I discovered is that Hot Reload does not work if you do changes to the reusable objects) - so **feedback highly welcome**!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';

class LongPress extends StatelessWidget {
  final DelayedButtonController controller = DelayedButtonController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              DelayedButton(
                controller: controller,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                  child: Text("Btn 1"),
                ),
                onTooShort: () =>
                    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Hold selection to vote! 1"),
                onTrigger: () => print("Btn 1 triggered"),
              ),
              Container(height: 30),
              DelayedButton(
                controller: controller,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                  child: Text("Btn 2"),
                ),
                onTooShort: () =>
                    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Hold selection to vote! 2"),
                onTrigger: () => print("Btn 2 triggered"),
              ),
              Container(height: 30),
              Text("Status Indicator:"),
              StatusIndicator(controller: controller),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DelayedButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const DelayedButton({
    Key key,
    this.controller,
    this.child,
    this.onTooShort,
    this.onTrigger,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final DelayedButtonController controller;
  final Widget child;
  final Function onTooShort;
  final Function onTrigger;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTapDown: (details) {
        controller.tapStart(this);
      },
      onTapUp: (details) {
        controller.tapEnd();
      },
      child: child,
    );
  }
}

class StatusIndicator extends StatefulWidget {
  const StatusIndicator({Key key, this.controller}) : super(key: key);

  final DelayedButtonController controller;

  @override
  _StatusIndicatorState createState() => _StatusIndicatorState();
}

class _StatusIndicatorState extends State<StatusIndicator>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation<double> animation;
  AnimationController controller;

  DelayedButton currentCaller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller =
        AnimationController(duration: const Duration(seconds: 1), vsync: this);
    animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1).animate(controller)
      ..addListener(() => setState(() {}))
      ..addStatusListener((status) async {
        if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          currentCaller.onTrigger();
          await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 300), () {});
          controller.reset();
        }
      });

    widget.controller.addOnTapStartCallback((caller) {
      currentCaller = caller;
      controller.forward();
    });
    widget.controller.addOnTapEndCallback(() {
      if (animation.value < 30 &&
          animation.value > 0 && // Value is 0 after completion & reset
          currentCaller.onTooShort != null) {
        currentCaller.onTooShort();
      }
      controller.reset();
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      color: Colors.grey,
      height: 100,
      width: 15,
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: FractionallySizedBox(
        heightFactor: animation.value,
        widthFactor: 1,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DelayedButtonController {
  List<Function(DelayedButton)> onTapStartCallbacks = List();

  List<Function> onTapEndCallbacks = List();

  void tapStart(DelayedButton caller) {
    onTapStartCallbacks.forEach((f) => f(caller));
  }

  void tapEnd() {
    onTapEndCallbacks.forEach((f) => f());
  }

  void addOnTapStartCallback(Function(DelayedButton) callback) {
    onTapStartCallbacks.add(callback);
  }

  void addOnTapEndCallback(Function callback) {
    onTapEndCallbacks.add(callback);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. first part, triggering after custom duration.
   You can define custom duration for long press with RawGestureDetector and LongPressGestureRecognizer.

custom gestures:

```
 var _customGestures = Map<Type, GestureRecognizerFactory>();
_customGestures[LongPressGestureRecognizer] = GestureRecognizerFactoryWithHandlers<LongPressGestureRecognizer>(
  () => LongPressGestureRecognizer(duration: Duration(seconds: 3), debugOwner: this),
  (LongPressGestureRecognizer instance) {
    instance
      ..onLongPress = () {} //you can define your action here, this callback will trigger when the duration end
      ..onLongPressStart = (details) {}
      ..onLongPressMoveUpdate = (details) {}
      ..onLongPressEnd = (details) {}
      ..onLongPressUp = () {};
  },
)
```

Widget:
*child* is the button in your case

```
RawGestureDetector(
    gestures: _customGestures,
    child:child,
)
```

2. To show some indicator, you can use animation controller (or any other animation method), and you can start when **onLongPressStart** triggered, and you can stop when **onLongPressEnd** triggered.
   **NOTE** longPress will trigger after a delay (~500ms)

Example:

```
class ExampleWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleWidgetState createState() => _ExampleWidgetState();
}

class _ExampleWidgetState extends State<ExampleWidget> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  static const _animDuration = 3;

  AnimationController _controller;
  Map<Type, GestureRecognizerFactory> _customGestures;
  Animation<double> _widthAnimation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = new AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: _animDuration),
    );

    _widthAnimation = Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 200).animate(_controller);
    _customGestures = Map<Type, GestureRecognizerFactory>();
    _customGestures[LongPressGestureRecognizer] = GestureRecognizerFactoryWithHandlers<LongPressGestureRecognizer>(
      () => LongPressGestureRecognizer(duration: Duration(seconds: _animDuration), debugOwner: this),
      (LongPressGestureRecognizer instance) {
        instance
          ..onLongPress = () {}
          ..onLongPressStart = (details) {
            _controller.forward();
          }
          ..onLongPressMoveUpdate = (details) {}
          ..onLongPressEnd = (details) {
          //check animation status, 
            _controller.reverse();
          }
          ..onLongPressUp = () {};
      },
    );

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawGestureDetector(
      gestures: _customGestures,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            width: 1.5,
            color: Colors.grey,
            style: BorderStyle.solid,
          ),
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        width: 200,
        height: 50,
        child: AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: _controller,
          builder: (context, child) {
            return Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Container(
                width: _widthAnimation.value,
                color: Colors.indigo,
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```